# Determine if Outlook Contact has been deleted using EWS 2007

Tags: exchangewebservices

i am able to retrieve lists of contacts for specified mailboxes using exchange web services. my issue is that some of the contacts returned have been deleted by the outlook user, and i need to determine which ones. how can i do this?

all the examples i've seen online use this method, but never for contacts.

i have tried setting the Traversal property of the ItemView variable to SoftDeleted, but that does not return anything.

below is the pertinent portion of my code:

```
ItemView itemViewDeleted = new ItemView(100);

itemViewDeleted.Traversal = ItemTraversal.SoftDeleted;

FindItemsResults<Item> deletedItems = svc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, itemViewDeleted);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the [`WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) folder. That is where my contacts go when I delete them.

#### There are (3) ways to delete a Contact. See TechNet for [Exchange terminology reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364755.aspx).

---

1. **Delete** (*moved to Deleted Items folder* - `WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems`)
2. **Soft Delete** (*moved to Recoverable Items folder* - `WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsDeletions`)
3. **Hard Delete** (*purged from mailbox* - `WellKnownFolderName.RecoverableItemsPurges`)

Comment: @RoastBeast See additional edits above - you may need to check recoverable items for soft/hard deletions.

Comment: thanks for the response - i was able to get all deleted contacts by reading from 1: WellKnownFolderName.Contacts with Traversal = ItemTraversal.SoftDeleted, 2: WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems with a search filter of SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Contact"), and 3: WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems with a search filter of SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Contact") with Traversal = ItemTraversal.SoftDeleted

Comment: unfortunately, i am using ews 2007 so the RecoverableItemsPurges and RecoverableItemsDeletions enumeration values are not available...those were introduced with dumpster 2.0 in exchange 2010 sp1.